# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement when inserting list to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

```
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table3(lane smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL, previousT int NOT NULL, averageT int NOT NULL, detectionT int NOT NULL, carID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)")

                mysql_lane1_output = [1, 28, 28, datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 7, 13, 24, 45, 297050)]
                print(mysql_lane1_output)
                lane_1_param = ','.join('?' * len(mysql_lane1_output))
                mysql1 = 'INSERT INTO test_table3 VALUES(%s);'% lane_1_param
                mycursor.execute(mysql1,mysql_lane1_output)
                mydb.commit()
```

I have created a table and want to insert list items into it and keep getting the error 'Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement'. I followed the answer on Stackoverflow for this code regarding inserting list to mysql.

Comment: Are you using pyodbc?

Comment: Not sure what that means? Probably nope.

Comment: I run your code in vs code but you have a lot of problem first of all you need %s not ? second what is a bigger problem datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 7, 13, 24, 45, 297050) is no int and you have 5 parameters you have to adress, so what do you want to save in detectionT

Comment: ultimately I want to include the current time and date(datetime.now()) for detectionT column. I was thinking of removing it from the list and adding the time separately if pssible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs in python 3.8.2

With

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
```

The following code is changed

- create table now is detectionT  DATETIME
- mysql_lane1_output  has now 5 elements
- lane_1_param  is changed to use %s instead of ?

code

```
 mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists test_table3(lane smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL, previousT int NOT NULL, averageT int NOT NULL, detectionT DATETIME NOT NULL, carID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)")
 mysql_lane1_output = [1, 28, 28, datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 7, 13, 24, 45, 297050),None]
 print(mysql_lane1_output)
 lane_1_param = ','.join(len(mysql_lane1_output)*('%s',))
 mysql1 = 'INSERT INTO test_table3 VALUES(%s);'% lane_1_param
 mycursor.execute(mysql1,mysql_lane1_output)
 mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Worked Perfect! Data sent to mysql. Thanks